# Feature: Option for larger view of each post in the "Search page"

Tags: feature-request, search

Currently when we search for some keyword in MSE we get a snippet view of each search result

[image]

I was wondering if we can include the option for "larger view", where we see a snippet of at least double the current size. Some reasons:

- As you can see from the above picture, it is almost impossible to figure out what each post contains even roughly.
- Even the current size of the snippet-view doesn't give enough information. For example, for [Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find a solution to the initial value problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4816345/use-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-to-find-a-solution-to-the-initial-value), it starts from "Part 2 I am given....", whereas if you click inside it starts with "Let's consider the initial value problem: dy/dx=x−2,y=(0)=1", which is far more descriptive.

> The suggestion is to include a button that allows the user to pick between the current view and one with a much larger view. Of course, the latter option will lead to fewer results per page, but at least we will be able to read more.